# Google Structured Data Reviews - best practices saving SEO

Tags: review, structured-data

I was implementing structured data in my companies website when i found this guide:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies

well, there's a point that bothers me... "note that reviews or ratings not by actual users are considered spammy".

I found references like this or worst (seo penalization etc) about fake reviews. Well my question is how can google know if a review is fair or not?

We had our own review system where users can post and rate, we can take google reviews too (but it will be a blend of both sources).

Now i'm a little bit scared about how to deal with it as there's no information about how to make google ensure your reviews related content.

If i post our own reviews (as we're doing, because google is google and our website is our website), could google "ban" our structured data, or worst, penalize SEO positioning?

Appart from reviews itself, there's a property **aggregateRating** with the best and worst rates, the reviews count and the average. Could it be interpreted as fake or fair too?

There's little information about this details that at first sight it seems that we all would consider important from my point of view.

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: sorry, let me move it and i'll close it by myself here

Comment: question copied to webmasters, i don't find the close question button so... if you can give me a point on how to do it i'll make it, thanks for all

Comment: [Link to question on Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/123546/17633)

Comment: @JoelBonetR: I think you can’t close it yourself. You can just leave it be; it should get 4 more close votes soon, and then it will get closed. -- I noticed that you seem to have two accounts here; you can flag a moderator (e.g., by flagging your comment) that you would like the accounts to get merged.